# MySQL HAVING 1 with sub select

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find a product that only has one option_group, imagine a set of products and product_options the main product only having one set of options and one or more bundled products which can contain multiple option groups

```
Products:
ID, Name, Price
1, Jacket, 10.00
2, Jacket & Hat, 15.00
3, Jacket, Hat & Gloves, 20.00
4, Hat, 5.00

Options
ID, product_id, option_group, option_name, option_value, option_code
1, 1, 1, size, small, jacksm 
2, 1, 1, size, medium, jackme
3, 1, 1, size, large, jackla
4, 2, 1, size, small, jacksm
5, 2, 1, size, medium, jackme
6, 2, 1, size, large, jackla
7, 2, 2, size, small, hatsm
8, 2, 2, size, medium, hatmed
```

in the above examples data the same jacket exists in both product 1 Jacket and product 2 Jacket & Hat and would exist in product 3 as well. I need to find the Jacket product 1 by using the option code even if the bundled Jacket & hat are purchased.

```
SELECT product_id, option_group FROM product_options WHERE product_id in(
SELECT DISTINCT(product_id) from products 
JOIN options OPTIONS products.product_id = product_options.product_id WHERE option_code = 'jacksm'
) 
group by option_group;
```

I can get all the ids and I can see the one I need with one product_id and one option group but I can't filter down to it I have tried adding HAVING 1 = count(option_group) but it returns and empty set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must `GROUP BY product_id` and set the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT product_id, MAX(option_group) option_group 
FROM product_options 
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT option_group) = 1
```